# ¿Es posible borrar de Google Play una App android publicada en versión beta?

Tags: android, google-play

En este día se me presenta un problema algo serio sobre el cual debo tomar una decisión:

Tengo publicada una App en Google Play Store en su **versión beta**. La misma tiene algunos miles de usuarios... porque se trata de una beta que todos pueden descargar.

Es una App que yo crée en mis inicios en Android, cometiendo algunos errores como son la forma de firmarla, el nombre del paquete que le di, etc, etc. Muchos de esos errores son irreversibles, sobre todo el nombre del paquete.

Con el tiempo la App ha crecido, funciona generalmente bien, pero tiene algunos comportamientos que no me gustan y que he buscado las causas sin encontrar una solución satisfactoria.

El hecho es que yo quisiera ahora borrar esa App y sustituirla por otra totalmente nueva, ya hecha con más conciencia :), partiendo desde cero e incorporando todas las funcionalidades de la App antigua (otro problema de esa antigua es que he ido haciendo muchas pruebas sobre ella y al final está llena de código que no he ido limpiando en su momento). En fin, que estoy decidido a publicar una nueva App definitiva y no ya en versión beta.

Entonces, después de esta larga introducción, para que puedan entender un poco la situación, quisiera saber:

**¿Es posible borrar definitivamente una App que está publicada en versión beta? ¿Cuál sería el procedimiento correcto?**

Lo que no quisiera es que en Play Store aparezca la App repetida y los usuarios se confundan sobre cuál debería instalar. Mi esperanza es que, dado que aún no he hecho una publicación definitiva de la App antigua, pueda borrarla.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que no se puede borrar en el momento que la has publicado. Una de las opciones que tienes es cambiarle el nombre y publicar la nueva app con ese nombre pero no creo que a los usuarios que ya la tienen la pudiesen actualizar... Te hablo lo que pasaba hace tiempo, ahora mismo no se si se podrá hacer otra cosa

Comment: Imagino que ya habrás visto esta respuesta pero por si acaso te sirve, aquí te lo dejo: [Delete an unpublished app from Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44360913/7064040), insisto en que no se si con "Unpublished" se refiere a terminar la fase beta

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano el hecho es que en Google Play Console no veo por ningún lado la opción `delete` o `unpublish`  ni nada parecido. Ni siquiera sé si una App en versión `Alfa` o `Beta` (realmente está en Alfa) se considera como *publicada*...

Comment: @rencinas no conocía esa respuesta, gracias por el enlace, la leeré más detenidamente. El hecho es que en Google Play Console tampoco veo opción de borrar o *despublicar*  la App, lo único que veo es un botón de *pasar a Producción* (realmente la App está en fase `Alpha`).

Comment: En la pestaña **Presencia en Google Play Store** ve a donde dice **Precio y distribución** alli dale a **NO PUBLICAR** y listo, es la única forma que conozco, la quitas de los listados de Play Store sin importar si es alfa o beta

Comment: @CarlosQuintero gracias, parece que el estado actual de las cosas es este: *Si anulas la publicación de una aplicación, los usuarios podrán seguir utilizándola y recibiendo actualizaciones, pero los nuevos usuarios no podrán buscarla en Google Play ni descargarla.*, según dice [el enlace *Más información* de la sección que me indicas](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282). Según eso yo podría en efecto tener una sola App activa en Play Store, avisando a los actuales usuarios mediante un módulo que tengo en la misma App para que borren la vieja.

Comment: es correcto, puedes desactivarla para nuevas instalaciones y notificar a los usuarios actuales de la nueva app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Es posible borrar definitivamente una App que está publicada en
>   versión beta? ¿Cuál sería el procedimiento correcto?

**No es posible**, en realidad precisamente se agrega una versión de aplicación para probar e ir cambiando de Alpha a Beta, posteriormente si todo funciona correcto se procede a publicar en producción.

Puedes dejar de publicar tu aplicación y esta no estará disponible para los usuarios ya sea en Alpha, Beta o producción, pero el registro del .APK queda registrado y no se puede eliminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede eliminar al subir el .apk sin haberlo salvado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo salvamos queda registrado en la consola de desarrollo y no se puede eliminar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En este caso no es posible  borrar el .apk, lo que necesitarías realizar es subir nuevamente otro .apk a Alpha testing pero con un versionCode mayor.**

Si no deseas que la aplicación que tienes en Alpha o Beta Testing sea visible a los usuarios, es importante deshabilites el testing:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tengo publicada una App en Google Play Store en su versión beta. La
>   misma tiene algunos miles de usuarios..

En el caso de haber escrito un nombre de paquete incorrecto, en realidad el nombre de paquete es un id de la aplicación. **Lo que puedes realizar es subir la aplicación con el nombre de paquete correcto pero sería una nueva aplicación.**

En cuanto a la firma puedes usar ahora el nuevo método y subir tu aplicación.

Comment: Pero yo quiero modificar el paquete totalmente, para darle el paquete exacto del dominio dedicado a la App, ya que lo escribí mal en mi novatada iniciando en Android Studio. ¿Eso es posible de alguna manera? Además quiero cambiar la forma en que he firmado la App, pues la firmé con un `debug.keystore`. Creo haber leído que en un pasado no se podía, pero como hablamos de plataformas que cambian constantemente, han habido muchos cambios, de hecho, y por eso también lancé la pregunta, por si alguien ha tenido situaciones parecidas recientemente.

Comment: La misma tiene algunos miles de usuarios... en realidad si cambias el paquete sería una nueva aplicación. Se puede dejar de publicar pero no eliminar el registro por esto es necesario un nuevo versionCode en el caso de usar el mismo paquete, si cambias a otro será una nueva aplicación.

Comment: Entiendo... mi mayor preocupación es que no haya dos aplicaciones en la Play Store, que serían en realidad la misma: la vieja y la nueva, y que los nuevos usuarios se confundan a la hora de descargar una u otra. En cuanto a los usuarios que tienen la vieja no hay problema, ya que yo programé la App para poder poner en una parte muy visible un aviso de que esa App dejará de ser actualizada, recomendando descargar la nueva. Mi interés es corregir el nombre del paquete, y lanzar la App con  código más limpio y mejor escrito.

Comment: una vez subido una app el nombre del paquete no se puede modificar, debes pesar si eso es muy importante o bien que si mantienes el nombre de paquete y la firma puedes que esos 1000 usuarios le llegue una versión final.

Comment: @A.Cedano para que no existan dos aplicaciones, simplemente puedes  dejar de publicar la que deseas y no aparecería al buscarla, en el caso de ALPHA y BETA testing simplemente deshabilitarlo.